# A physical quantity that is a real combination and commutability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Suppose that a matrix

$$A ~=~ x_1 B + x_2 C$$

is a linear combination of two self-adjoint matrices $B$ and $C$.

I'm interested in when $A$ represents a physical quantity.

When the linear combination is a complex combination, then $B$ and $C$ have to be commutable for $A$ to represent any physical quantity, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38255/2451) Phys.SE post.

Now suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are real. What happens in this case? If $B$ and $C$ are noncommutable, does $A$ still represent physical quantity?

Answer (score 2):

*Yes,* if $B$ and $C$ are self-adjoint $n\times n$ matrices (and even if they are mutually non-commuting), and if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are real numbers, then

$$A= x_1 B + x_2 C $$

is also a self-adjoint matrix $A\!=\!A^{\dagger}$, and hence a physical [observable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable).

Comment: In infinite dimensions, $C$ is Hermitian but not necessarily self-adjoint. One needs some domain compatibility condition for the selfadjointness of $C$.